# Playing video from youtube and other pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a **video_player** package which nicely shows videos stored in firebase storage via their links in firestore. But replacing link to video in storage with **youtube link doesn't work**.

My point is to make an app which would show videos from youtube and maybe other pages like vimeo.

Maybe someone has done it already?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This package](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) does the work perfectly

*I've used it on Flutter version < 2.0 so I don't know if it will work if you're using the current framework version

Comment: I just have tried to use this code on android but coping example gives me an exception